# Azure Application Gateway Unavailability and generate Alert

Tags: azure-application-gateway

My Use case is, as soon as App Gateway gets down due to any reason an alert should have generate and follow its action.

However when i tried to put a resource health alert in Azure, it seems Azure Doesn't provide the Unavailable Event for it. Hence, when app gateway went down it didn't generate any alert but when it back to available state, alert generated consisting its current health status and can have previous health status as well.

App Gateway Metrics, i didn't find much which exactly fix my use case. and same with Kusto queries.

I have also tried with Azure Service Health Alert but that wont help me as it comes at region level.

Can you please help me is there anyway by which i can fix my use case.

put an alert against App Gateway and expecting an email as soon as app gateway went down or stopped

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to be notified as soon as the application gateway goes> down unfortunately  Azure doesn't provide an unavailable event that you can use to trigger an alert you can make use of metrics.

You can utilize a range of metrics from Azure Monitor, such as HTTP requests, response times, and error rates, to monitor performance on your App Gateway.  You can set up an alert that is triggered whenever a certain metric passes a predetermined threshold or stays below a predetermined value for a certain period. By doing this, you'll be alerted when your App Gateway is not operating as it should, allowing you to take action before it progresses.

To make alert in Application gateway check the below workaround:

In your application gateway or Log Analytics workspaces click on alert like below

[image]

In condition you can select unhealthy host count like below:

[image]

Try to create an action group like below:

[image]

Created Alert:

[image]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/eZJOJJJ.png]

In your Log Analytics workspaces -> under logs you can able to see unavailability and unhealthy request failures manually like below:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and OperationName == "ApplicationGatewayAccess" and httpStatus_d > 399
| summarize AggregatedValue = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h), _ResourceId
| render timechart
```

[image]

***Refer***: [Monitoring Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/monitor-application-gateway)

Additionally, you can use the Diagnostic setting like below:

[image]

Application gateway performance logs allow you to see app gateway instances are performing, using these logs you can able to see total request, and the number of healthy and unhealthy backend instance counts,  and this all will be collected every 60 sec in the performance log

To more in detail ***refer*** this link:

[Alert to known the status of health probe for application gateway](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/67f5ec32-51c9-4710-8e5b-91c113b261b8/alert-to-known-the-status-of-health-probe-for-application-gateway?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork) by *Subhash*

[azure-docs/configure-alerts-with-templates.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub  by Abby](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/application-gateway/configure-alerts-with-templates.md)